# "jar:file" vs. only "file:" reference when retrieving resources in Java

Tags: java, linux, jar

This question is related to my question

[Jetty 11.0.11 - 404 on html file in \src\main\webapp\static - maven embedded fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608551/jetty-11-0-11-404-on-html-file-in-src-main-webapp-static-maven-embedded-fat)

What --EXACTLY-- does "jar:file" mean as a Java resource reference, vs. just "file:"?

And how is that influenced by the operating system ran under?

E. g. using this resource reference in Jetty webserver, in Windows with Oracle JDK 17, files are found as resources and parsed by Jetty webserver:

```
file:///D:/Projects/verdi_2/target/classes/static/,AVAILABLE}{file:/D:/Projects/verdi_2/target/classes/static}
```

Using this resource reference in Jetty webserver, in Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS with Oracle JDK 17, NO files are found and nothing can be parsed by Jetty webserver:

```
jar:file:/usr/src/verdi/verdi-12-JDK17-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/static
```

Is there a difference in how a Linux version of JDK interprets "jar:file" vs. how a Windows version of the JDK interprets "jar:file"?

**EDIT**: The related issue is the Jetty webserver apparently can no longer serve resources directly out of a JAR file it is itself embedded in. This is now a GitHub bug ticket at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/8549

Comment: Jar files are zip files. They usually don’t have entries for directories. You have to refer to the files you want access, e.g. `index.html`.

Comment: *They usually don’t have entries for directories* They in fact usually do. It's just that it's not normally useful *in this context* to refer to them, as only the 'file entries' are usable

Comment: @Holger there might be no directory entries in something you looked at but I assure you *it* does create directory entries - I just used it to create the jar to test the code I posted. The very first thing that ```jar```  tells me is *adding: root/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: root/a/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)*, of which entries *both* are directories, which list perfecty well with ```jar tf```

Comment: @g00se I have correct myself. `jar` does create directory entries when you a) specify directories explicitly or b) tell it to recursively add files and directories. It doesn’t create them when you specify a list of files or patterns like `*.class`. I just verified that 1) Java 8’s `rt.jar` does not contain any directory entries and 2) *if* the jar contains directory entries, `getResource` using the name of the directory *does* work. So since it doesn’t work in the OP’s case, the build setup in use didn’t create directory entries. Which is quite common.

Comment: @Holger using g00se's Java testing code, I can find the folder /static in my jar and copy files out of it to the local filing system in the Oracle JRE 17 in Linux. So it does appear to be there. I can also extract the JAR using unzip and see the folders and files. The problem that prompted the question is that OTHER software running in the Linux JRE (e. g. Jetty webserver) does not "understand" a "jar:file" reference and cannot dereference such a URI it to find the file specified by it in its own JAR. To try and fix that I first had to understand what "jar:file" means...  thx for commenting!

Comment: @Stefan when you used that testing code to copy files from the jar, you obviously used URLs pointing to files within the jar. Which is the point: it works for files. Trying to use `getResource` for a directory, however, only works if there is a pseudo entry for the directory, which is, as said, unreliable. Semantically, tools consider directories as existing when there is at least one entry whose path starts with the directory’s path. You could use the `FileSystem` API to access the jar file and it would allow you to access and traverse the structure as if the directories exist.

Comment: @Holger that makes sense... my problem though is that the classes I need to have access that resource is compiled code from the Jetty project, which as you say behaves in the above manner you describe. I can only surmise my entire design is faulty and I need to start from scratch. I'm finding it impossible to force a file / folder structure "into" a class / member structure, so Jetty webserver can do even something EXTREMELY basic such as finding a file inside the jar it is running inside of... the confusing thing is everything works as long as I stay in the IDE - deploy the JAR and it breaks.

Comment: When you run inside the IDE, the classes and resource aren’t packed into jar files but residing on the default filesystem which has directories. So trying to access the corresponding `file:` URLs always works. That’s one of the dangerous things about testing inside the IDE. Another would be that, e.g. under Windows the filesystem is case insensitive so using the wrong case could stay unnoticed until deploying as jar. Other IDEs create jar files even when running inside the IDE, so you’re closer to the production environment when testing.

Comment: Am I correct in stating that I need some kind of compile-time conditional, e. g. so that the compiler "sees" one set of code for running the application in the IDE, and another set of code for running the application as a JAR? E. g. what works in the IDE is switched off via a compile-time switch when I compile for a JAR (not that it will help as I still got no idea what "working inside a JAR" code in my use case will look like...) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file:` is the beginning of a general file url. `jar:file:` is that for a jar file particularly, with a view to referring (usually) to a particular entry in a jar. Here's an example you can run (obviously with your own jar url) where you can save an entry as a file (given by the parameter to the app)

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.net.URL;

public class JarUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("jar:file:root.jar!/root/a/b.txt");
            Files.copy(url.openStream(), Paths.get(args[0]));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What --EXACTLY-- does "jar:file" mean as a Java resource reference, vs. just "file:"?

You're mischaracterising the URL a little bit. The string until the first : decides the 'scheme' of a URL, so, the pertinent question is: How does `jar:` work. The `file:` part is a smaller aspect of a sub-part of the jar bit.

### How does `jar:` work

The format is `jar:(URL-of-jar)!(path-inside-jar)`

Where `URL-of-jar` is *itself* a valid URL (and `file:` is just one way to do that. So is `http`, for that matter), and `path-inside-jar` is not a URL but a path.

The meaning is: First, resolve the 'URL-of-jar' URL. This gets you a jar file. Then, open the jar file, and retrieve the resource at the stated path.

So, to pull this one apart:

> `jar:file:/usr/src/verdi/verdi-12-JDK17-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/static`

The jar is located at URL `file:/usr/src/verdi/verdi-12-JDK17-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and the resource it is referring to is the `/static` resource *inside* the jar found at the given URL.

### How does `file:` work

That's not java-specific; `file:` is a generally available URL scheme. You can even type it in a web browser. The more general URL formatting scheme is `scheme://server/resource`, but with `file:`, server doesn't apply (it is by definition local to the system you are on), so usually its put as `file:///foo`, i.e. - an empty 'server' part. Because 3 slashes is a drag to type, I guess, `file:/resource` is allowed by some 'URL parsers', including java's in this regard, so, `file:/usr/...` simply maps straight to a local folder: `/usr/src/verdi/verdi-12-JDK-etc`, as in, if you type `ls /usr/src/verdi/verdi-12-JDK17-jar-with-dependencies.jar` on the command line on your system, it would show a result (and if it does not, this URL would fail to find anything).

> And how is that influenced by the operating system ran under?

It isn't. `file` URLs are a general concept that work on any platform. Of course, `/usr/src/verdi/etc` is never going to work correctly on a windows platform. Or on anybody else's machine. The problem isn't "Oh no! This won't run on another OS!". The problem with file URLs, especially absolute ones, is "Oh no! This will not run on any machine other than this one!".

> `file:///D:/Projects`

I've explained the triple slashes earlier. This is the standard windows 'scheme' for how to stick paths in `file` URLs: Always forward slashes (even though windows normally uses backslashes), and treat the disk letter as if it is a 'drive' in the 'root': `/D:/Project` is URL-ese for:

```
D:
cd \Project
```

There is no difference in OS at all - `file:` URLs are handled by 'interpret this file URL the way any file URL would be interpreted on this machine'.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, upvoted. That makes sense. My problem is that in my use case with Jetty webserver, file: references work and can find resources, while no jar:file references work (ever) - but only in a Linux JRE.

Comment: Yes. But this question isn't about why it doesn't work, this question is: "What does `jar:file:` mean". See the other question :)

Comment: Touche :) - I tested this g00se's code example and the Oracle 17 JRE in Linux can read from jar:file resources and copy them out fine. So it DOES work, but the software I have (Jetty webserver) cannot do what the native JRE code can do... so onward on that one. THANKS for taking the time and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the related question

[Jetty 11.0.11 - 404 on html file in \src\main\webapp\static - maven embedded fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608551/jetty-11-0-11-404-on-html-file-in-src-main-webapp-static-maven-embedded-fat)

which prompted this post is in the long series of posts beneath this GitHub issue for jetty:

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/8549

In essence, eventually I had to first clean up my Maven pom.xml (see this thread for the discussion and for links to a pom.xml example that is compliant with Maven Shade plugin and Jetty 11.0.11 requirements and standards) then at the end of the day hardcode a link to the JAR file to find the HTML, JS, etc. resources Jetty was to serve out as a webpage. Also put in a conditional where, on compiling, I need to specify if the code will run "in-IDE" (in my case, Netbeans 14) or "in-JAR" - e. g. in a detached JRE elsewhere than the Netbeans 14 IDE.

Also dropped using the Jetty WebAppContext class and started rendering web content out of a normal ServletContextHandler.

Hopefully this may help someone upgrading Jetty from Jetty 9.xxx to 11 and finding that it all falls apart.

For details as to why they changed so much, see the GitHub link (the last few entries are apropos.)

The github discussion also contains full working source code (startJettyc method) that solved the issue of getting a 404 in a detached, non-IDE modality where the JAR was being run in an JRE separate from an IDE.

Stefan